# Image didn't change when updating the updatepanel using Generic Handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, ashx

I'm doing some code where the program will display the output came from database.
Then after 5 seconds it will display the next data and so on.

Here's my code for getting the data from database:

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Timer1.Enabled = false;
 loadUserData();
 UPThis2.Update();
 Timer1.Enabled = true;  
}

//This code is for loadUserData

lblName.Text = row[1].ToString();
Global.__publicUserID = lblName.Text;
imgSales.ImageUrl = "~/image.ashx?Global.__publicUserID";
```

Then for image.ashx

```
using (FGSQL.SqlCommandEx sqlCmd = new FGSQL.SqlCommandEx("SP_GETCURRENTUSER"))
                {
                    sqlCmd.CommandObject.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fldUserID", Global.__publicUserID);
                    if (sqlCmd.GetDataTable().Rows.Count != 0)
                    {
                        DataTable _TblProfile = sqlCmd.GetDataTable();
                        foreach (DataRow row in _TblProfile.Rows)
                        {
                            context.Response.Buffer = true;
                            context.Response.Charset = "";
                            context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                            context.Response.ContentType = "logo";
                            context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Client Logo");
                            context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])row[0]);
                            context.Response.Flush();
                            context.Response.End();
                        }

                    }

                }
```

Added:
The problem is...Its getting the image once only..after 5 seconds its not changing the image anymore and its not going to the image.ashx..

How can I fix this one?

Thank you

Comment: Refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472131/why-doesnt-aspupdatepanel-refresh-an-image

Comment: can I see the code of Update Panel?

Comment: I would answer similar - add something unique to picture url, it will bypass browser caching.